# Semi-colon in Makefile rule definition

Tags: makefile

I am seeing a number of rules in a Makefile that look like this:

```
$(PATH)/foo.inc:;
include $(PATH)/foo.inc

$(PATH)/bar.inc:;
include $(PATH)/bar.inc
```

Is the semi-colon at the end of the rule definition a no-op or does it have a particular meaning?

Comment: In this context, it is a no-op.  If it was followed by something on the same line, it would not be a no-op.

Comment: It is no-op, but thing to keep in mind is that it prevent implicit rules to take place. With just `:` and no recipe, the implicit rule (if any exists) will be used, with `:;`, there is empty recipe.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A semicolon on the line with the target-prerequisite is the first command line to execute for this rule, at least in GNU make.

From chapter 5 of the manual:

> The commands of a rule consist of shell command lines to be executed
>   one by one. Each command line must start with a tab, except that the
>   first command line may be attached to the target-and-prerequisites
>   line with a semicolon in between.

In your case since there is no command after the semi-colon then it ends up being a no-op.