# GNU make - implicit rule is not used, but static pattern rule is

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following `makefile` (and any `hi.c`):

```
.PHONY: analyze-%


hi: hi.c
    gcc -o $@ $<

%.json: %
    touch $@ # actually created by analysis-tool

analyze-%: %.json # why does this not work?
```

As my comment in the `makefile` points out, the implicit rule does not work:

```
$ make analyze-hi
make: *** No rule to make target 'analyze-hi'.  Stop.
```

It only works after transforming it into a static pattern rule:

```
...
analyze-hi: analyze-%: %.json
```

Why is this the case? Shouldn't `make` be able to figure this out on its own, without me having to explicitly write the full target name? There is no ambiguity or anything (as far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern rules must have recipes.  If they don't have a recipe then they're not creating a pattern rule, they're canceling one.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html

A static pattern rule, contrary to what's implied by its name, is not actually creating an implicit rule (pattern or suffix rule).  It's creating *explicit* rules, just based on a pattern.  Explicit rules don't have to have recipes.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't expect this to be the reason. I now use a semicolon at the end of the rule, so it is 'analyze-%: %.json ;' (found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12322983/9505725). This is a pretty clean solution.